# How to change the color of a graph in PySide2

Tags: python, pyside2, qtcharts

I'm making a simple graph in PySide2 and was just wondering if you can change the color to something else. This is currently my code.

```
series = QtCharts.QLineSeries()

series.append(0,0)
series.append(1,7)
series.append(1.2,14)
series.append(1.3,21)
series.append(1.4,28)
series.append(1.5,35)

self.chartView = QtCharts.QChartView(self)
self.chartView.chart().addSeries(series)
self.chartView.chart().createDefaultAxes()
self.chartView.resize(600, 480)
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Forgot to mention that, the color of the line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the line you must set it with [setColor()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html#color-prop):

```
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        series = QtCharts.QLineSeries()
        series.append(0,0)
        series.append(1,7)
        series.append(1.2,14)
        series.append(1.3,21)
        series.append(1.4,28)
        series.append(1.5,35)

        self.chartView = QtCharts.QChartView()
        self.chartView.chart().addSeries(series)
        self.chartView.chart().createDefaultAxes()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.chartView)
        series.setColor(QtGui.QColor("salmon"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

If you want to change the background color you must use the [setCackgroundBrush()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#setBackgroundBrush) method of `QChart()`:

```
self.chartView.chart().setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QColor("gray"))
```

[image]